# Keyboards and mouse of my Laptop (HP DV7) behaving weirdly

Tags: laptop, usb, keyboard, mouse, anti-virus

I have HP Pavilion DV7 laptop.. for last few weeks I am having problem with the key board and the mouse.Few keys gets pressed automatically. Then few keys performs wrongly like "shift" key acts as "paste" command. This problem happens occasionally.

Similarly the mouse acts weirdly sometimes. Upon left click it straight away tries to throw the item(folder or file) to the recycle bin.

I have tested with external usb keyboards (and mouse) but still the problem is there.
The problem happens occasionally and on re-starting the laptop for several times it goes off..to resurface again may be few days later.

I have antivirus in my system which scans regularly and displays everything is clean.

Comment: Possibly similar problem: I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on an HP dv7 (dv7-6c95dx). I have keystrokes that get dropped, or keys that repeat. For example, I could type the word "keystrokes" and get "kkkkkrokes".  I had been using 11.04 on this system until recently, and I *think* the keyboard problems started when I upgraded, but I'm not certain.